# when div is closed , how can print in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, printing

I have many Divs in My page, they are closed and opened with function(click), I want it to open divs and print when I click on the print button.
Now when I click on the print button, I want to show like the below picture:
[Print Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUOxI.png)

How can I auto open divs, when I click on print button? or are there other ways?
I just want to print inside divs

**this Is My Button Code:**

```
<button
  style="border: none; background-color: white; margin-right: 80px"
  printTitle="Print"
  [printStyle]="{
    div: {
      display: 'block',
      'text-align': 'right',
      direction: 'rtl',
      height: 'auto !important'
    },
    span: { display: 'block', margin: '10px 0' },
    p: { display: 'block', margin: '20px 0' },
  
  }"
  printSectionId="section"
  ngxPrint
>
  <img
    src="../../../../../assets/images/icons8-send-to-printer-96.png"
    class="m-3"
    style="cursor: pointer; width: 40px; height: 40px; background-image: none"
  />
</button>
```